# rect.offsetTo arrtibute

Tags: android, canvas, rect

Can some explain to me about `rect.offsetTo(`)?

I mean, does it draws the rect in a new location? or only sets the location of the top and left as new and relatively the bottom and right of the rect?

**for example:**

if i have a rect,

```
    Canvas c=null;
    Paint p=new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    Rect r=new Rect(10,10,20,20);
    c.drawRect(r,p);

    i=0;
    while(isRunning){
       i=i+5;
       r.offsetTo(10+i, 10+i);
    }
```

will i see on the screen now that the rect is moving?

Comment: moving??? what does setting the Rect coords have to do wirh it?

Comment: if it sets every round of the loop a new corrdinates for the rect, it will look like the rect is moving

Answer (score 1):

As defined by the Android documentation:

```
rect.offsetTo(int newLeft, int newTop)

Offset the rectangle to a specific (left, top) position, keeping its width and height the same.
```

So to answer your question, the offsetTo method will draw your rect in a new location specified by the newLeft coordinate (distance from the left side of the canvas to the left side of your rect) and the newTop coordinate (distance from the top of the canvas to the top of your rect).

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#offsetTo%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: and by that you also mean that it will delete the rect in the last location..?

Comment: It isn't deleting the rect, it is just changing the coordinates of the existing rect. So if you draw a rectangle using your initial rect, then call offsetTo, then invalidate and redraw your canvas...then the rectangle will be drawn with the new rect...Therefore a new rectangle will be drawn and the old one will be gone.

Comment: In your View, just call the invalidate() method and onDraw() will be redrawn.